# PostgreSQL - How to create a table with value saved as PST Timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Had a look at the documentation: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html

Table 8-9 shows `timestamp [ (p) ] with time zone` but the square brackets and normal brackets are putting me off and there are no examples to show how to implement that.

e.g. if I had the following, how would I make the `some_time` column hold PST Timestamps and not UTC?

```
CREATE TABLE "mytable" (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  some_time TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a column with a time zone specified timestamp type.
The **p** in the documentation means **precision**:

> time, timestamp, and interval accept an optional precision value p

About the values of **p**:

> For the time types, the allowed range of p is from 0 to 6 when eight-byte integer storage is used, or from 0 to 10 when floating-point storage is used.

I think you want to use `timestamp without time zone` columns, then convert them to the desired time zone with `AT TIME ZONE`:

```sql
SELECT some_time AT TIME ZONE 'PST', some_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+2' FROM mytable;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb079/1)